# PHP Heroku app won't let me access sub-directories

Tags: php, apache, heroku

Using PHP Heroku web app to upload all my PHP homework assignemnts. I make a subdirectory "assignment1" to my root directory which I have set to htdocs, within assignment1 is an index.php file, when I go to the url to my heroku site and type in "myurl.herokuapp.com/assignment1/index.php" it gives me a 500 error.

However my default index.php page, directly under htdocs loads correctly and everything.

Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 htdocs/
```

directory tree:

```
htdocs/
  |
  |_ assignment1/
  |       |
  |       |_ index.php
  |
  |_ index.php
```

Seems to be an Apache issue where 
Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, my php code for the index.php in the assignment 1 folder was faulty and thats why it wouldn't load and gave me a 500 error.

Love heroku! lol